# cannot ping each other in same lan on openwrt with virtual port and physical port

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, router, vmware, openwrt

my openwrt-x86 has been running for a while inside exsi virtual environment(it's a VM,eth0 eth1 is virtual NIC of exsi),and one day I tried to add a pass through port(eth2 physical) into this openwrt as a lan port so I can access the lan managed by this openwrt by physically connect a wire into eth2, but I found that I can got ip address and dhcp normally,but cannnot connect other ipaddress  in the same lan except the openwrt itself and wan network.

my config file of openwrt was
root@OpenWrt:/etc/config# cat network

```
config interface 'loopback'
        option device 'lo'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
        option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
        option ula_prefix 'fdc8:982a:611a::/48'

config device
        option name 'br-lan'
        option type 'bridge'
        list ports 'eth0'
        list ports 'eth2'
        option ipv6 '0'

config interface 'lan'
        option device 'br-lan'
        option proto 'static'
        option ip6assign '60'
        option ipaddr '10.0.0.1'
        option netmask '255.255.0.0'

config interface 'wan'
        option device 'eth1'
        option proto 'dhcp'
        option metric '5'

config interface 'wan6'
        option device 'eth1'
        option proto 'dhcpv6'
```

for example I got 10.0.0.10 dhcp ipaddr by physically connected to eth2,then my wan network still fine I can go google,but when I tried ping 10.0.0.151(a vm that in openwrt's lan) and got icmp not reachable

```
[root@master1 ~]# ping 10.0.0.151
PING 10.0.0.151 (10.0.0.151) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

From 10.0.0.10 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.10 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.10 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

and the route table on 10.0.0.10 seems fine

```
[root@master1 ~]# ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ens192 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.10 metric 100
10.0.0.0/16 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.10 metric 100
```

Answer (score 0):

solved,due to Exsi set internal switch NIC

Promiscuous Mode =false
Forged Transmits =false

by default,so vm in virtual lan cannot receive ARP response delivered,enable them to make it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).